# X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

From a linux client I'd like to use X11 forwarding in a CentOS 7 server.

I've followed many advices found in Internet:

1) Checked that the `xauth` package is installed.

2) The `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file contains the following lines:

```
AddressFamily   inet
X11Forwarding   yes
X11UseLocalhost no
```

3) I've restarted the `sshd` daemon:

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

but when running from the client this command:

```
ssh -X user@myserver.com xeyes
```

I get this error message:

```
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
Error: Can't open display:
```

What else am I missing?

*UPDATE*

Versions:

- Client: OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i-fips 6 Aug 2014
- Server: OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

More info:

- The `-v` flag in the `ssh` command doesn't show any intereting information.
- `journalctl -x -u sshd.service` in the server doesn't show any information apart from: `Accepted publickey for user from IP port XXXX`

Comment: use `ssh -Y user@myserver.com xeyes`. Is the `xauth` installed **on the server**?

Comment: Yes `xauth` is installed.   Sadly, `-Y` has the same result as `-X`.

Comment: Full verbose log from server and client might get some more information. Also what version of openssh are you using on server and client?

Comment: I've used the -v flag but no interesting info appears.
Client: OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i-fips 6 Aug 2014
Server: OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

Comment: Client can use `-vvv` to get more verbose logs. Also the server config accepts `LogLevel DEBUG3` to get more information (after service restart).

Comment: Unix and Linux Stack Exchange has a general question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111519/ .